make command throws different name for gcc-12
Trying to install vmware modules as shown in this: https://superuser.com/a/1733280, but whenever I try to run make, this error shows up
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0

I can't really find info on this online, I'd like some help as I am not that experienced with Linux in general.

When Ubuntu (Canonical) compiles the kernel they specify the architecture and that it might be a cross compile on their make command line. Example from the log file for a mainline PPA kernel compile:
make ARCH=x86 CROSS_COMPILE=x86_64-linux-gnu- HOSTCC=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-14 CC=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-14 RUSTC=rustc HOSTRUSTC=rustc RUSTFMT=rustfmt BINDGEN=bindgen KERNELRELEASE=6.13.0-061300rc1- CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH=y KBUILD_BUILD_VERSION="202412012327" CFLAGS_MODULE="-DPKG_ABI=061300rc1" PYTHON=python3 O=/home/kernel/COD/linux/debian/tmp-headers INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/home/kernel/COD/linux/debian/linux-libc-dev/usr -j32 headers_install

Resulting in the following CONFIG_CC_VERSION_TEXT in the kernel configuration file:
CONFIG_CC_VERSION_TEXT="x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-14 (Ubuntu 14.2.0-4ubuntu2) 14.2.0"

When I compile the kernel I am not cross compiling and such so I just use this (I always time the kernel compile):
time make -s -j13 olddefconfig bindeb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-stock

Resulting in the following line in the kernel configuration file:
CONFIG_CC_VERSION_TEXT="gcc (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0"

But if I also specify the architecture and cross-compile stuff:
time make ARCH=x86 CROSS_COMPILE=x86_64-linux-gnu- -s -j13 olddefconfig bindeb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-test

Then that same line in the kernel configuration file becomes:
CONFIG_CC_VERSION_TEXT="x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0"

but is otherwise unchanged.
So try adding ARCH=x86 CROSS_COMPILE=x86_64-linux-gnu- to your make command line.
